# Is every finite, connected k-regular graph a quotient of the infinite k-regular Tree?

Tags: graph-theory, covering-spaces

I know that every finite, connected (undirected) $k$-regular graph has the infinite $k$-regular tree as its universal cover. But I'm not sure if this implies, that every finite, connected, $k$-regular graph is a quotient graph of the infinite $k$-regular tree. If the answer is yes, how can you prove it?
So in other words: Are finite, connected, $k$-regular graphs exactly the same as quotients of the infinite $k$-regular tree?

Or even more general: If $X$ is a connected graph with universal cover $\tilde{X}$, is it true that $X$ is a quotient Graph of $\tilde{X}$? And how can you construct this quotient for a given graph $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even more generally: if $G$ is *any* covering graph of $H$, with covering map $f : V(G) \to V(H)$, then take the relation $x \sim y \iff f(x)=f(y)$ on the vertices of $G$. The quotient graph $G/\sim$ is isomorphic to $H$.

The isomorphism $H \to G/\sim$ takes a vertex $v \in V(H)$ to the fiber $f^{-1}(v)$, which is an equivalence class of $\sim$ and therefore a vertex of $G/\sim$. We can check that:

- If two vertices $x,y \in V(H)$ are adjacent in $H$, let $v \in f^{-1}(x)$. Restricted to $N(v)$, $f$ is a bijection between $N(v)$ and $N(x)$, so there is a $w \in N(v)$ such that $f(w)=y$. The edge $vw \in E(G)$ tells us that $f^{-1}(x), f^{-1}(y)$ are adjacent in $G/\sim$.
- If two vertices $f^{-1}(x), f^{-1}(y)$ are adjacent in $G/\sim$, then we can find $v \in f^{-1}(x)$ and $w \in f^{-1}(y)$ that are adjacent in $G$. Restricted to $N(v)$, $f$ is a bijection between $N(v)$ and $N(x)$. Since $w \in N(v)$, we know $y \in N(x)$, so $x$ and $y$ are adjacent in $G$.